# POWERPIVOT - Look up max value for a new column from existing columns

Tags: excel, powerpivot, dax

I'm essentially trying to create a new column that has a city given MAX dollars spent in a city for a given program, and that the CITY value isn't "BAD". Data example below

```
PROGRAM | CITY | DOLLARS SPENT | NEW COLUMN

   1    |   X  |      $20      |     ?
   1    |   Z  |      $30      |     ?
   1    |   Y  |      $40      |     ?
   1    |  BAD |      $50      |     ?
   2    |   X  |      $30      |     ?
   2    |  BAD |      $50      |     ?
```

So, if City = "BAD", i want the new column to return the Max City by Dollars Spent in the New Column.

Ideally the output would look like this.

```
PROGRAM | CITY | DOLLARS SPENT | NEW COLUMN

   1    |   X  |      $20      |     X
   1    |   Z  |      $30      |     Z
   1    |   Y  |      $40      |     Y
   1    |  BAD |      $50      |     Y
   2    |   X  |      $30      |     X
   2    |  BAD |      $50      |     X
```

u/tiger gave a great plain excel response. Still looking for a solution to do completely within powerpivot! Hopefully that all makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't the output be `{Y, Y, Y, Y, X, X}` because city Y spent the Max dollars ($40) on Program 1 excluding `BAD` and city X spent the Max dollars ($30) on Program 2 excluding `BAD`?  Why are your results `{X, Z, Y, Y, X, X}`?

Comment: No, I only want to change the City where City = "BAD". Where city used to be "BAD", I want it to return the largest City that wasn't "BAD"

Comment: So... If City <> "Bad" then City else Largest City?  You don't want Largest City returned for all of them?  Is there a particular reason why not?

Comment: Yeah, the reason is just that BAD isn't an acceptable value for a City, but I don't want to reassign all of the dollars spent on the program. Therefore I'm attempting to reassign where that value isn't acceptable only.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a formula that does as you've described based on the sample data provided.  In cell D2 and copied down:

```
=IF(B2="BAD",INDEX($B$2:$B$7,MATCH(1,INDEX(($A$2:$A$7=A2)*($B$2:$B$7<>"BAD")*($C$2:$C$7=MAX(INDEX(($B$2:$B$7<>"BAD")*($A$2:$A$7=A2)*$C$2:$C$7,))),),0)),B2)
```

It will give results like so:

[image]

Comment: I should have added this in the title. But do you know how to do this in Poiwerpivot? No index funtion there

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not :(

Comment: I was able to use your method. However due to automation limitations, I need to keep it all contained within Powerpivot formulas as that is where the data is contained. Removing the data from the powerpivot tables makes it static, which is dangerous for frequent updates. Your method is a great short term fix, but doesn't completely solve the problems at hand. Thanks again for your response, /tigeravatar!

Answer (score 0):

Try this calculated column:

```
=IF(
  YourTable[City]="BAD",
  CALCULATE(
    VALUES(YourTable[City]),
    TOPN(
      1,
      FILTER(
       ALL(YourTable),
       YourTable[City]<>"BAD"
       && YourTable[Program]=EARLIER(YourTable[Program])
      ),
      YourTable[Dollars Spent]
    )
  ),
  YourTable[City]
 )
```

Comment: I'm getting an error with this formula, because the measure is refering directly to the column YourTable[City] without performing any aggregation on that column. Is the TOPN misplaced?

Comment: @JamesM. Did you use this as a measure of a calculated column? Try a calculated column

Comment: No, I had used it as a formula directly in the calculated column.

Comment: @JamesM. apologies for the error. I've fixed a few problems in the formula. It needed VALUES around the CALCULATE(YourTable[City] section. And for some reason, ALLEXCEPT wasn't working as expected.